# when playing playlist, how to prevent the "next up" window from showing?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I want to play items in the playlist one by one smoothly, making users feel like they are just watching one video, but the "next up" window shows up when a video is about to finish, and the "playlist" button constantly exists, which affect the user experience I want to achieve. I am aware that I can use CSS to block those, but I think there should be some setting options about this. Though I have gone through the API reference and playlist configuration options but did not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try including the following parameters as part of the setup config block:

```
{
  ...
  "nextUpDisplay":false, // NOTE: Only added as of JW 7.10.1
  "visualplaylist":false, // Added as of JW 7.0.1, but then removed (from documentation) when the playlist changed to overlay style in JW 7.7.0 - should still function though
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just checked the "nextUpDisplay" parameter in JW 7.11.0 - and whilst it removes the "popup" box, the "Next Item" button still appears in the control bar - thus this needs to be removed using CSS. Typical half-a-job solutions from the JW Team.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this Github [thread](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/1477)? It has a couple solutions to disable the next up and playlist UI

Disable next up

```
.jw-releated-dock-btn .jw-overlay {
      display: none !important;
}
```

Turn off the playlist UI

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
    visualplaylist: 'false'
});
```